# Use a tikz variable outside tikz environment... or something that could do that whatsoever?

Tags: tikz-pgf, grouping

I want to use a variable that could be used in TikZ code to get an external data file, and outside this code to define a legend associated. TikZ won't let me use `\caption` inside its environment, and the label solution doesn't work...

For example with various external drawing I want to be able to use the name of the drawing in a caption pretty much like that:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \def\tex{texsx}
    \includegraphics[width=2cm]{\tex};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{drawing of \tex}
\end{document}
```

It sounds trivial to me but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: What kind of variable is it? You should be able to use a `\caption` inside a `\node`. Please consider adding a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: MWE is now done !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be a problem with scoping. If you move the `\def` to be before the `tikzpicture` things should work. Alternatively using a `gdef` (which makes the definition global) instead of `\def`, should also work.

Comment: worked indeed, thanks ! dunno why but I thought \def was something defined in tikz environment.